# Flutter not debugging

Tags: flutter

After updating flutter to version 3.10.0 from 3.7.5. the app is no longer starting in debug mode (android and windows) and even opening. Below is the log I get. In version 3.7.5. I had no issues, but after the update we need to do because of the build server it is no longer working.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...               main.dart:1
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Does someone else have this issue? Or maybe something I missed in the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current solution we went for is the revert back to 3.7.5 this version works without problems. Possible problem is that 3.10.0 is faulty so will post an issue on the github.